# Racket - Transform a natural number to a specific base

Tags: racket

I am trying to convert a number N from a base 10 to the B base. I am currently trying to use this method, yet I am receiving an error that I do not understand. I am currently a begginer in racket and I would like to understand what I am doing wrong.

```
(define (num->base n b)
   (if (zero? n) '() (append (num->base (quotient n b) b) (list (modulo n b))))
)
```

+edit: Code above is completly functional, I let it here in case somebody needs it!

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: @ScottHunter `('())` is clearly erroneous, as are the double brackets around `convert` in the 4th line. ;-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: And you don't think it in Mr. Walker's interest to see the connection between his error(s) and the error message(s) he is seeing?

Comment: @ScottHunter Actually, many newcomers to Scheme don't realise that brackets are syntactically significant until someone points it out to them, especially if they come from other languages. I see questions about this on SO all the time.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: Maybe if someone pointed out the connection between the error messages they see & the errors they make, they wouldn't make so many appearances on SO.

Comment: Thank you, @ChrisJester-Young I have updated the post, yet, now I receive an error involving the "you are adding a number" to a list, shouldn't append() add at first the '() then it will continue with the (modulo n b) ?

Comment: @TimothyWalker You're getting close. You just need to replace `'(modulo n b)` with `(list (modulo n b))`. (There are very important differences between `'(foo bar)` and `(list foo bar)`.)

Comment: Yep @ChrisJester-Young just figured it out, thank you a lot!